# Iniciar variables con datos de un Input

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Estoy desarrollando una App en Ionic... en un módulo estoy mostrando datos de la base de datos. Dichos datos traen un id, dicho id lo estoy colocando en un  para después en mi controlador recuperar ese id, y hacer acciones sobre ese registro. El problema comienza aquí, en mi controlador declaré un arreglo tal que asi **nombreArreglo: any[] = []**. Dentro del constructor definí dos index del controlador **nombreArreglo['index1'] = ''**.

En mi vista definí un Input  en el cual asigno (Como ya habia dicho el id de un registro).

Cuando accedo la vista, me da un error, el error es porque mi arreglo en el constructor lo estoy definiendo como vacio, y en la vista estoy definiendo ese arreglo con un dato.

[[image: Aca la imagen del error[1]]

Comment: Puedes colocar código de ejemplo para entender mejor el problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gracias por sus respuestas... agrego mi código como ejemplo

**MI CONTROLADOR**

encuesta: any[] = [];

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public navParams: NavParams,
              public userService: UserProvider,
              public toastCtrl: ToastController, 
              public http: Http,) {

```
this.http; Http;

this.encuesta['idencuesta'] = '';

this.http.get(url).subscribe(data =>{
  //console.log(data.json())
  this.lists = data.json();//Esto es de otro arreglo :d
  console.log(this.lists['registros']);//Esto es de otro arreglo :d

}, error=> {
  console.log(error.json());
});
```

}

votarSi() {

```
let data = new URLSearchParams();

data.append('encuesta[idCiudadano]', this.encuesta['idCiudadano']);
data.append('encuesta[idencuesta]', this.encuesta['idencuesta']);

  this.http.post(url, data)
   .subscribe(data =>{
   },error =>{
     console.log(error.json());
   })
```

}

**VISTA**

En la vista Básicamente, pongo un input con el id de una encuesta, para saber que encuesta se va a votar. En el Controlador con el Append recupero ese dato (idencuesta) que se va a votar. Es ahí, dónde salta el error.. que la variable está inicializada como vacia y en el input esta definida con un valor.

[image: Esta es la Imagen del Error]

Answer (score 0):

mas o menos entendí tu pregunta  deberías documentarla un poco mas para poder entenderte

lo que entendí es que quieres definir un array  y luego rellenarlo de datos  par  para ello deberías definir el array con todo y campos  ( justamente antes de el contructor )

algo asi

```html
  public Form = {
        campo1:"",
        campo2:"",
        campo3:"",
        campo4:"",
        
   };
```

si vas a llenar el array con datos en el constructor deberías utilizar

```html
this.Form.campo1 = "El valor que le quiero asignar ";
```

si los quieres llenar desde un input

```html
<ion-item>
          <ion-label color="primary">campo1 </ion-label>
          <ion-input placeholder="escriba el valor" name="campo1" [(ngModel)]="Form.campo1" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Hola, y gracias por la respuesta..! Mira.. mi código

encuesta: any[] = []; //Declare mi arreglo

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public navParams: NavParams,
              public userService: UserProvider,
              public toastCtrl: ToastController, 
              public http: Http,) {

    this.http; Http;
    this.encuesta['idencuesta'] = ''; //Inicio mi arreglo en esa posición en vacio

  }

Comment: si pero en si Cual es tu problema ?   no puedes  guardar lo  que escribes en el imput ?

Comment: o quieres crear un array para  que cada uno de los campos de tu formulario se guarden en dicho array ?

Comment: Hola..!! En sí, quiero definir un **input** con un valor de la base de datos, y, en mi constructor, recuperar ese dato con un arreglo, utilizando el ngModel. El punto es que, en mi constructor defino mi arreglo como vacio, y como mi **input** tiene el mismo nombre en el ngModel del arreglo que estoy definiendo como vacio en el constructor, me marca ese error... Estoy definiendo en mi **Constructor** un arreglo vacio, y en el input le estoy dando por defecto un dato.